# File replacements in angular.json causing errors in Angular 11 library

Tags: angular, configuration, angular-library

I created an Angular 11 library. Inside the angular.json file for the library workspace, I am trying to add **fileReplacements** similar to how it is done for a normal angular app. The code I added inside configurations section in angular.json is shown below.

```
"configurations": {
     "production": {
        "tsConfig": "projects/cw-component-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json",
        "fileReplacements": [
          {
                "replace": "projects/cw-component-lib/src/lib/scss/theme.scss",
                "with": "projects/cw-component-lib/src/lib/themes/themenew.scss"
          }
        ]
     }
 }
```

The cw-component-lib is the project which is insdie the projects folder of the library. Now when I try to run the build command **ng build cw-component-lib --prod** I get the below error

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(fileReplacements).
```

I don't know what exactly is causing the issue. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: Not possible

Angular libraries are built using a different builder (`@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr` rather than `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser`) which sadly doesn't support `fileReplacements`.

See issue about the same thing: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12361

> Hi, thanks for reporting this but the library builders doesn’t support
> any of those properties.
>
> Valid properties are listed here:
> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular_devkit/build_ng_packagr/src/build/schema.json

(dead link) see here instead: https://github.com/angular/angular-devkit-build-ng-packagr-builds/blob/master/src/build/schema.d.ts

```
/**
 * ng-packagr target options for Build Architect. Use to build library projects.
 */
export interface Schema {
    /**
     * The file path for the ng-packagr configuration file, relative to the current workspace.
     */
    project: string;
    /**
     * The full path for the TypeScript configuration file, relative to the current workspace.
     */
    tsConfig?: string;
    /**
     * Run build when files change.
     */
    watch?: boolean;
}
```

There's no (easy) workaround that I know of. I'm looking for it myself.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Trevortni never. And I've since started using NextJS instead so I probably never will.

Comment: @Trevortni any news with angular 14?

Comment: @Edo2610 Not that I know of. I ended up specifying what I needed in the main app and having the library get at it by injection.